# List<object> Remove objects past a certain index (and Speed for doing so)

Tags: c#, list

I am storing a bunch of url's in a list, There is expected to be many (around 3,000,000 at the most, more commonly around 50,000 to 200,000).

For an example of what I need to do:

ListOfStrings

---

```
    [0]www.google.ca  
    [1]www.yahoo.com  
    [2]www.wikipedia.com  
    [3]www.youtube.com  
    [4]www.gmail.com  
    [5]www.stackoverflow.com  
    [6]www.steam.com  
    [7]www.microsoft.com  
    [8]www.ebay.com
```

I need to remove everything past string[5]. Should I just create a loop that does

```
while (ListOfStrings.Count>5)
{
    ListOfStrings[6].Remove
}
```

Or is there faster method of doing this? (I was thinking possibly using `.GetRange(0, ListOfStrings.IndexOf())` however there will be a maximum of 25 strings that need to be removed, so I'm not sure which one would be more efficient)

I am Also going to need to do the reverse (everything before Entry [5]) only I will need to remove many more of the strings, rather then 25 max. It will be more like 50,000 removals.

Comment: What's your idea about `list.Take(5)`? If you really want to remove items from original list, then `list.RemoveRange` is suitable, if you need to return a subset, then `Take` is suitanle. you can also mix `Take` with `Skip`.

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer for you, hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments:

**If you want to don't touch the list and just want to take a subset:**

- If you want to take a subset from beginning of the list , you can use [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method:

  `var result= list.Take(5).ToList(); //The result is first 5 items`
- If you want to take a subset from middle of list, you can use [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) methods:

  `var result = list.Skip(3).Take(5).ToList(); //the result is item 4 to 8`

**If you want to remove items from the list:**

- You can use [`RemoveRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8):

  `list.RemoveRange(5, 4); //it changes list and removes all items above 5`

Comment: Thank you That explains my Options Nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Enumerable.Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx)?

```
var result = list.Take(5);
```

Comment: Is there a list.TakeRange ? I need all strings before [5]. Problem is that could Be ALOT of strings (as I mentioned If I remove all past [5] then theres a max of 25, where as there could be hundreds if not thousands Before [5]. I could only make the example list so large.